Is it possible to send a user certificate when recording a script with JMeter?
I try to record a test script and the server identifies/authenticates users by certificates, then it is needed to send a user certificate.

I imported my p12 certificate in a jks keystore in PKCS12 format.
I defined the properties javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType (PKCS12), javax.net.ssl.keyStore and javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword in a properties file.

But it seems like the certificate is not sent.
Does someone know how to check if the certificate is sent to the server ?
Does someone achieve  to record a script with a server that authenticates users by certificates ?
Is it  even possible ?
I read a lots of articles about using a user certificate to execute a test script but no one to record one. For example this one : Sending client certificate with JMeter load test.
Thanks for any helps.

In fact this is possible, there are two options :

using -D options to valuate the properties in the jmeter command
using -S option to define the properties in a dedicated file

In fact properties defined with the -p option are not the same than those defined with the -S option.

You need to define these properties not in a random "properties" file, but in system.properties file which lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.
See Configuring JMeter user manual chapter for more details on various JMeter properties file and their usage.
Also there is an alternative way of recording a JMeter test which doesn't require messing up with proxies and certificates: JMeter Chrome Extension
You will need to supply user certificate(s) during replay though via keystore and system properties otherwise your requests won't be authorized

humm this is an option but i prefer to leave jmeter folder as is and to define my own configuration files that i can manage with meaning names and according to each environements.
